# Make a child call a function from its parent AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

So I've been reading a lot about inheritance and circular dependency and I see no way around this. Still a little new to multiple classes. My document class creates Field. My Field class creates player and pushes bitmapData from the Tile MovieClip. I want player to be able to draw that bitmapData to the field. Engine.as(document class):

```
package  {
import flash.display.MovieClip;

public class Engine extends MovieClip {

    private var field:Field;
    public static var _tilesData:Array = [];

    public function Engine() 
    {
        field = new Field();
        field.x = 0;
        field.y = 0;
        addChild(field);
    }
}
```

Field.as:

```
package  {
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.display.BitmapData;
import flash.display.Bitmap;

public class Field extends MovieClip{

    private var player:Player;
    private var sampleTile:Tile = new Tile();

    public function Field() 
    {
        player = new Player();
        player.x = 0;
        player.y = 0;
        addChild(player);

        GetSampleTiles();
    }

    public function GetSampleTiles()
    {
        for (var i:int = 0;i < 3; i++)
        {
            sampleTile.gotoAndStop(i);

            var graphicData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(32,32);
            graphicData.draw(sampleTile);

            Engine._tilesData.push(graphicData);
        }
    }

    public function DrawATile(tileToDraw:BitmapData)
    {
        var newTile:Bitmap = new Bitmap(tileToDraw);
        newTile.x = player.x;
        newTile.y = player.y;
        addChild(newTile);
    }
}
```

}
Player.as:

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.display.BitmapData;
import flash.display.Bitmap;

public class Player extends MovieClip 
{
    public var _inp:Input = new Input();

    public function Player() 
    {
        addChild(_inp);
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, HandleKeys);
    }

    public function HandleKeys(e:Event)
    {
        if(_inp.keyUp)
        {
            y -= 32;
        }
        if(_inp.keyDown)
        {
            y += 32;
        }
        if(_inp.keyLeft)
        {
            x -= 32;
        }
        if(_inp.keyRight)
        {
            x += 32;
        }
        if(_inp.keySpace)
        {
            parent.DrawATile(Engine._tilesData[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Is there a better way of doing this than I am seeing? When I put DrawATile function in Player.as it works... but the tiles move around with the player.

Comment: Ugh.... I keep doing this. I feel so dumb. parent.addChild(newTile);  *face palm*

Comment: So has this been answered? If so, create an answer of what you did to solve this and mark it correct. And don't worry its just a part of learning, I've screwed up code today and felt like an idiot, but the more you do it the better you get.

Answer (score 0):

I placed the DrawATile function in Player.as and in it I add the newTile to parent like this - parent.addChild(newTile). that way it adds it to whatever its parent is and not to itself.